# Show that $f(x)=\sin|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: limits

Show that $f(x)=\sin|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

I tried running it through the formula and got:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow0^-} \dfrac{\sin h}{h}$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow0^+} \dfrac{\sin h}{h}$

Do I need to show they're not equal to prove it? I don't see how they're not equal though, unless I've done something wrong in my working.

Comment: the first should be $-1$ and the second should be $1$.  Have you tried graphing $\sin|x|$ to see this?

Comment: You're dealing with $\sin |x|$ not $\sin x$ as shown in your attempt. You need to show that there exists a sharp point at $x = 0$. Try drawing the graph. It becomes more obvious.

Comment: In your try you seem to forget that you are dealing with $\sin|x|$ (and not $\sin x$). Also if $x$ is practicized on LHS then it should be practicized on RHS as well (not $h$).

Comment: Around $x=0$, you have $\sin |x| \approx |x|$ (so that you understand what's going on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x<0$, $$\frac{d}{dx}\sin|x|=\frac{d}{dx}\sin(-x)=-\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)$$
Thus, the limit is:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-\sin h}{h}=-1$$
Which is not equal to $1$.